# Identifier not found or not unique. on adding new prduct smart contract

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

what im i doing wrong here, this is smart contract based on e-commerce that allow users to create store list goods and sell. im getting the above error on line 61[image: an e-commerce smart contract]

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

//import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract MarketPride {
address payable owner;
uint256  productCounter;

struct Product {
string title;
string category;
string description;
address payable seller;
uint256 price;
uint256 rating;
uint id;
uint256 timestamp;
}
products[++productCounter] = newProduct
//creating an object of all store
struct storeStruct {
string name;
string description;
uint256 id;
address creator;
}
Product[] products;

mapping (uint256 => Product) public productById;
mapping (uint256 => storeStruct) public stores;

```
constructor () {
  owner == msg.sender;
}
```

modifier onlyStoreOwner() {
require(owner == msg.sender , 'only store owner can delete a store');
_;
}

event payment(
address indexed _from,
address indexed _to,
uint256 _price
);

function checkUserExist(address pubkey) public view returns(bool){}

function createStore(string calldata _name, string calldata _desc) public view{
require(checkUserExist(msg.sender) == false, 'pls register an account first');
require(bytes(_name).length>0, "Store name needs to be included");
require(bytes(_desc).length>0, "description plays an important role");
}

function listProductToStore(
string memory _name,
string memory _category,
string memory _description,
address payable _price,
uint256 _rating,
uint256 _time) public {
require(checkUserExist(msg.sender) == false, 'pls register an account first');
Product memory newProduct = Product({
buyer: address(0),
seller: msg.sender,
id: products,
name: _name,
category: _category,
description: _description,
price: _price,
rating: _rating
});

```
  }
```

function payForProducts(address _from, address _to, uint256 price) public payable {
}

function getAllStore() public view returns(storeStruct[] memory){}

function getAllProduct() public view returns(Product[] memory){}

function getStoreName(address pubkey) external view returns(string memory){}
}

Comment: Please, include the code as text. It is much easier for testing than using an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you created your struct instance with the name `Product` when you have created the struct with the name `productStruct`. Replace your line 61 with:

```
productStruct memory newProduct = productStruct({ ...
```

Also, seems like you are not storing your struct instance anywhere. Make sure to update that too.

```
products[++productCounter] = newProduct
```

UPDATE: The final code:

```
productStuct memory newProduct = productStuct({
        buyer: address(0),
        seller: msg.sender,
        id: products,
        name: _name,
        category: _category,
        description: _description,
        price: _price,
        rating: _rating
    });
    products[++productCounter] = newProduct
```

Comment: where should i add lhe 2nd code you wrote

Comment: Just below the struct

Comment: Linter: Parse error: extraneous input '=' expecting {'from', 'error', 'calldata', 'revert', 'callback', 'override', 'constant', 'immutable', 'leave', 'internal', 'payable', 'private', 'public', 'constructor', 'receive', Identifier} [undefined]
Expected identifier but got '='

Comment: i just updated the question with an original code as text can you pls check it out and hlp

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thanks a lot, im sorry if seem stressing. i got this error after that    Named argument "buyer" does not match function declaration.
Named argument "name" does not match function declaration. on the productstructs({})

Comment: Happy to help. Please click on accept the answer. This will help a lot. :)

Comment: what about this error i got  Named argument "buyer" does not match function declaration. Named argument "name" does not match function declaration.

Comment: I would recommend you to read about structs a bit. As I can see here, you are trying to input `name`, `id`, and `buyer` in the struct instance, but your struct declaration doesn't have any variable representing that value. You cannot add new variables in the struct.